# Instrumenting ARM binaries on a X86/Linux machine using Valgrind

Tags: arm, valgrind

Is there any way for instrumenting an ARM binary using Valgrind which runs on a X86/Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Valgrind does not "instrument" binaries. It runs the unmodified binary inside an emulator (well, you can view it like that anyway), and intercepts the memory accesses as they happen.

Valgrind is therefore highly architecture-specific, and the Valgrind that runs on x86 can do nothing useful with an ARM binary.

However, Valgrind does have (possible incomplete) [support for the ARMv7 architecture](http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html), so you should be able to run that on your target device and analyse your code that way.

If Valgrind will not work reliably with your device (not enough memory? Too slow?) then you might try running it on the x86 machine inside QEMU (user mode). On Ubuntu (and probably other distros) it is sufficient to install the QEMU package, and then ARM binaries will magically run via translation, as if they were on the target, with no further effort (although dynamically linked binaries will have difficulties finding their libraries). You can then run Valgrind for ARM and your own code on your development machine.